# Make unique index on json column

Tags: mysql, json, indexing, unique

How to make unique index on json type column in mysql? for example, I have translations column with slug property. I need unique slug among languages [translations column image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWKet.png)

`` CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `root_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `translations` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `published_from` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `published_till` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `display_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `images` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `posts_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  KEY `posts_root_id_foreign` (`root_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `posts_root_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`root_id`) REFERENCES `roots` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `posts_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `admins` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci; ``

Comment: Provide table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]` with better example data as ascii data table (not images) or provide a sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 3):

JSON is not a replacement for the features of RDBMS.

As you insert rows, extract the "slug property" and put it into a separate column that is declared to be `UNIQUE`.  Although it takes a little more work, it will be cleaner and more efficient in the long run.

Ditto for any other columns that you *frequently* need to filter or sort on.  (Don't do it to all columns.)